# jquery draggable droppable with sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to make it so that when I put all the words in the bottom tiles I can then sort them between the "Most Like Me to Least Like Me" droppable areas. Right now, I can drag and drop them to the different boxes, but it will put two draggables on top of each other in one droppable area. I want it to push the other draggable out of the box and NOT allow two draggables to be in the same droppable area, while still allowing the user to change their mind if they make a mistake or want to resort them. Please find the code below:

HTML

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="cardPile">
  <div id="question1">Spontaneous</div>
  <div id="question2">Decisive</div>
  <div id="question3">Realistic</div>
  <div id="question4">Logical</div>
  </div>

  <div id="cardSlots">
  <div>Most Like Me</div>
  <div>2nd Most Like Me</div>
  <div>3rd Most Like Me</div>
  <div>Least Like Me</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Add some margin to the page and set a default font and colour */

body {margin: 30px;font-family: "Tahoma", serif;line-height: 1.8em;color: #333;}

/* Give headings their own font */

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
}

/* Main content area */

#content {
  margin: 65px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Header/footer boxes */

.wideBox {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.wideBox h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* Slots for final card positions */

#cardSlots {
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  background:#D9F2FF;
}

/* The initial pile of unsorted cards */

#cardPile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#cardSlots {
  width: 910px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
 #cardPile {
width: 910px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
/* Individual cards and slots */

#cardSlots div, #cardPile div {
  float: left;
  width: 195px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

#cardSlots div:first-child, #cardPile div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}

#cardSlots div {
  border-style: dashed;
}

#cardPile div {
  background: #009;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}

#cardPile div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

$( init );

function init() {
  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  {
    $('#cardPile div').draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  {
    $('#cardSlots div').droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );



  }

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
    var slotNumber = $(this);
    var cardNumber = ui.draggable;  

    if ( cardNumber1 == cardNumber1 ) {
        ui.draggable.addClass ( 'correct' );
        ui.draggable.position( {of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
        ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    }
}

}



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U7m73/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(init);

function init() {

    $('#cardSlots').sortable({placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"});
    // Create the pile of shuffled cards
    {
        $('#cardPile div').draggable({
            containment: '#content',
            stack: '#cardPile div',
            cursor: 'move',
            connectToSortable: '#cardSlots'

        });
    }

    // Create the card slots
    {
        $('#cardSlots').droppable({
            accept: '#cardPile',
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: handleCardDrop

        });}

    function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
        var slotNumber = $(this);
        var cardNumber = ui.draggable;

        if (cardNumber1 == cardNumber1) {
            ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
            ui.draggable.position({
                of: $(this),
                my: 'left top',
                at: 'left top'
            });

          ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);

        }

    }

 }
});
```